# How to scroll some other element or header after 40px(n px) of body scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to scroll up the header with slower than body's scrolling speed.

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
          Header will be scroll after 40px scrolling of body
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        ...
        ...  (this content will scroll with normal scrolling speed.)
        ...
        <div class="el1">
             This div will scroll after 50% scrolling of body with slow speed
        </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...

    </div>
</body>
```

How can I achieve this? With the use of javascript or css in angularjs app?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of AngularJs do you use?

Comment: First version of angular (angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class that apply the fixed styles to the header.

```
<div class="header" ng-class="{'fixed-header': showFixedHeader}">
      Header will be scroll after 40px scrolling of body
</div>
```

In your controller you should add the listener to the body to track the scroll event

```
angular.element(document.body).addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (scrollTop > 40) {
        $scope.showFixedHeader = true;
    } else if (scrollTop < 40) {
        $scope.showFixedHeader = false;
    }
}, false);
```

});

```
.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thnks for guide me.
But  i want as

After page loading first of all heade will be fixed in the top.

After 40px scrolling of body the header should be start to scrolling up with slower speed than body's scrolling speed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case on a project i am working on, I solved it using this library.

https://github.com/harm-less/angular-sticky

Hope this is helpful,
Cheers!